# How to avoid entering Cloud credentials in many apps

Tags: sync, dropbox, cloud

I was about to set up my FolderSync with Dropbox, but noticed that I can't browse my cloud the way I can with the Dropbox and other could applications (Which generally doesn't sync but let you navigate your files).

Is there an app that will let me do both?
(Could be just opening the website)

Comment: Olav, I'd suggest to move the backup part to a separate post and, as *Is there an app for X* questions are considered off-topic, slightly re-phrase the paragraph above it :) I took your question by its title, so it's on-topic to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Cloudii](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getcloudii.android). I don't use the cloud myself, but if this app keeps it promises, it...

> is the best app to manage all your cloud services within a single app. Cloudii brings full service integration as well as a powerfull synchronization tool.

It even integrates multiple cloud services (currently: Google Drive, Dropbox, Skydrive and Box -- more to come). According to its description, it lets you both navigate your cloud-stored files and keeping them in sync (the screenshots support this idea).

Note, however, that the free app is a 14d trial only, which afterwards requires an in-app purchase. I don't know the price, but as one comment put it: *I'll be glad to buy the developer "coffee"!*

Comment: "This app is incompatible with all of your devices".  Also it doesn't have a lot of downloads.

Comment: OK, so the first outrules it. The reason for the second might be it's quite young :) You might want to check the "Cloudiness" section of [this German overview](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/433708/) for alternatives. Never mind the "German", you will surely understand the listing :)